# Distance between icons in a navbar

Tags: android, xml

How can I change the distance between the icons in this navbar? Is there any way to do so.
[image: the navbar currently]

I tried searching online for solutions but couldn't find anything.

```
<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
            android:id="@+id/navigation"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_height="59dp"
            android:background="@drawable/nav_background_curved"
            android:visibility="visible"
            app:itemHorizontalTranslationEnabled="false"
            app:itemIconTint="@android:color/white"
            app:itemTextColor="@android:color/white"
            app:labelVisibilityMode="labeled"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:menu="@menu/navigation" />
```

this is the current code for the navbar

Answer (score 0):

BottomNavigationView is set to space between. You can get the look you want by updating the icon size values ​​or the padding values.

Samp : `app:itemPaddingTop="2dp"`